# Android TV: No Activity found to handle intent Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION

Tags: android, android-tv, scoped-storage

So, declaring

> android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

permission and directing the user to the Settings page via

> Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION

works fine on phones & tablets (physical & emulator) with Android 30+.

It does, however, crash on the Android TV Emulator with latest API30+ images.
I don't have a physical test device atm, but does this mean Foogle removed this permission from Android TV without clearly mentioning it in the docs?

The consequence of this is no more file manager apps on Android TV, since the Storage Access Framework (SAF) is enforced targeting API 30+.

Comment: "but does this mean Foogle removed this permission from Android TV without clearly mentioning it in the docs?" -- it means that screen is not available, at least not via that direct `Intent` action.

Comment: Your app does not have to crash if you catch that exception. Further i do not agree with your consequence.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?